# Is Eitri the King of Dwarves in the MCU as well?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

In the comics, Eitri is the King of the Dwarves of Nidavellir. However in the MCU, there is no mention that Eitri is the king (except the wiki fandom page, which as usual, does not cite its sources).

So is Eitri, in the MCU, confirmed to be the **King of Dwarves**, just like in the comics? Or was he just a dwarf who worked at the Nidavellir's forge?

Comment: Assistant _to_ the King of Dwarves.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Yes

Thor certainly thinks so in *Avengers: Infinity War* when talking to the Guardians about going to Nidavellir.

> **Thor:** Only Eitri the dwarf king can make me the weapon I need.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Infinity War*</sub>

It is further mentioned in *Thor: The Dark World Prelude* Issue 1 about how the Nine Realms started to fall into chaos due to Asgard failing to protect them after Thor destroyed the Bifrost at the end of *Thor*.

> [image: The trolls look to the city of Dwarven forges on Nidavellir ready to strike]
>
> **Thor:** The Troll lords know it, as well. For so many millennia, they have coveted the Dwarven forges. Once they realise that Asgard cannot come to King Eitri's defence, they will strike.